# decodedImage from base64 return nil while after assign into UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I tried to decoded my image Data from NSData base64EncodedString but i got nil when i putted decodedData into decodedImage

This is my code

```
self.base64String = snapshot.value.objectForKey("profileimage") as! String
var decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: snapshot.value.objectForKey("profileimage") as! String, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
var decodedImage = UIImage(data: decodedData!)

println(decodedData!) // return <89504e47 0d0a1a0a 0000000d 49484452 00000153 00000116 08020000 0054bce3 fc000000 01735247 4200aece 1ce90000 001c6944 4f540000 00020000 00000000 008b0000 00280000 008b0000 008b0001 904ef7da>

println(decodedImage) // return nil
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of image is it?  (It seems awfully small.)

Comment: It has a PNG header, but seems to be truncated.

Comment: Yes, the data appears to be corrupted.  The last few bytes appear to not follow the [PNG spec](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Structure.html), and there aren't nearly enough bytes for any real image.

Comment: just some image from ios simulator

Comment: "What kind" means PNG, JPG, etc.  But examining the hex above reveals that it's a PNG, so the question is moot.

Comment: (The net here is that your Base64 value is truncated.  Since you have chosen to not tell us where it came from we cannot help you further.)

Comment: Ah i just upload some default image from ios simulator into my db with base64 and then try to get it back.
So i don't know what kind of it.
But my function is ok right?